# Regex to match start and end while capitalizing the middle part of a string between square brackets

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm trying to do a find and replace using regex, my goal is to replace the start and end of the text but leave the middle intact.

I have an [example I tried on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cO8lqs/13281):

```
\[[^(]+?\]
```

It selects the text I need to keep. Stretch goal is to capitalise the first letter of the middle portion.

So, if the input is

```
The quick brown jumped over [the] lazy dog.
```

The result should be

```
[The]
```

Comment: And are you going to work just with regex101? You are not going to use the regex anywhere else?

Comment: Please provide one sample input and sample output, that will help

Comment: @VickyKumar its included in the description

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew im using that to test but i will be notepad++ for the find and replace.

Comment: output should be ` [The] ' but when i do the find and replace it should not delete the 'The'

Comment: Try `.*(\[[^][])([^][]*\]).*` and replace with `\U$1\E$2`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew pretty much  - i'll test your solution now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

**Find What**: `.*(\[[^][])([^][]*]).*`
**Replace With**: `\U$1\E$2`

**Details**

- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `(\[[^][])` - Capturing group 1: `[` and any 1 char other than `[` and `]`
- `([^][]*])` - Capturing group 2: any 0+ chars other than `[` and `]` and then `]`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.
- `\U$1\E$2` - uppercase all chars in Group 1 and then just append Group 2.

See the Notepad++ demo:

[image]

Comment: Thats pretty much what I'm after however can it not delete the line and not retain the '[' or ']' for eg.`The quick brown jumped over [the] lazy dog` should now be The quick brown jumped over The lazy dog

Comment: @marwaha.ks It is easier then, `\[([^][])([^][]*)]` => `\U$1\E$2`